# css focus animation is not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I had just built this input field with simple animation. This code works like in this way that when you I click on input field then label the will go up but problem is that when I click on the label it does not work and when I click right of the label then it works perfectly.

In case of the first label if I click on Label or right of label both works perfect but only in case of the first label.

I don't know what I am doing mistake

Codepen Link https://codepen.io/nitishk72/pen/GdBegz

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
for (var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
  input[i].addEventListener('focus',show);
  input[i].addEventListener('focusout',hide);
}
function show(){
  this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].classList.add('focused')
}

function hide(){
  this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].classList.remove('focused')
                       
}
```

```css
body { 
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.frm{
  width:360px;
  margin:40px auto;
  box-shadow:0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  font-family:sans-serif;
  background:#fff;
  padding:20px;
}
.line{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:30px;
}
label{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:0;
  transition:0.4s;
  z-index:10;
}
label.focused{
  transform: translateY(-125%);
  font-size: .75em;
}
input{
  padding: 12px 0px 5px 0; 
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="frm">
    <center><h2>Simple Form</h2></center>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="name">Enter Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="name">Enter Your Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="name">Enter Your Password</label>
      <input type="text" id="pass">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my answer is first @nitishk72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` attributes were wrong on the second and third labels (they were all linking to the first input id):

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
for (var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
  input[i].addEventListener('focus',show);
  input[i].addEventListener('focusout',hide);
}
function show(){
  this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].classList.add('focused')
}

function hide(){
  this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].classList.remove('focused')
                       
}
```

```css
body { 
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.frm{
  width:360px;
  margin:40px auto;
  box-shadow:0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  font-family:sans-serif;
  background:#fff;
  padding:20px;
}
.line{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:30px;
}
label{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:0;
  transition:0.4s;
  z-index:10;
}
label.focused{
  transform: translateY(-125%);
  font-size: .75em;
}
input{
  padding: 12px 0px 5px 0; 
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="frm">
    <center><h2>Simple Form</h2></center>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="name">Enter Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="email">Enter Your Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="pass">Enter Your Password</label>
      <input type="text" id="pass">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not `name` attributes but `for` attributes

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

Change label `for` like

```
<div class="line">
      <label for="name">Enter Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="email">Enter Your Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="pass">Enter Your Password</label>
      <input type="text" id="pass">
    </div>
```

Comment: haha just saw the solution, wanted to post it, thought "should refresh, shouldn't I" and there you answer was :P

Answer (score 0):

You give wrong `for` value.

> `for` value and `id` value should always be same.

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
for (var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
  input[i].addEventListener('focus',show);
  input[i].addEventListener('focusout',hide);
}
function show(){
  this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].classList.add('focused')
}

function hide(){
  this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].classList.remove('focused')
                       
}
```

```css
body { 
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.frm{
  width:360px;
  margin:40px auto;
  box-shadow:0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  font-family:sans-serif;
  background:#fff;
  padding:20px;
}
.line{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:30px;
}
label{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:0;
  transition:0.4s;
  z-index:10;
}
label.focused{
  transform: translateY(-125%);
  font-size: .75em;
}
input{
  padding: 12px 0px 5px 0; 
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="frm">
    <center><h2>Simple Form</h2></center>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="name">Enter Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="email">Enter Your Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <label for="pass">Enter Your Password</label>
      <input type="text" id="pass">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine you just add label for the wrong element.

For example:

```
<div class="line">
  <label for="name">Enter Your Password</label>
  <input type="text" id="pass">
</div>
```

In the `for` attribute you should give id of element to which should the label point. In your case all the label points to an element with `id="name"`.

Just change `for="name"` to `for="pass"`.

Answer (score 0):

just add below new property in your css and check

```
input{
   z-index:11;
    background:none;
    position:relative;
}
input:hover{
 cursor: default;
}
input:focus{
 cursor: auto;
}
```